# JQuery: Change value when value of other input field is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the value of an input field whenever the value of another one is changed.

I've tried for a while and I can't seem to get it to work

```
<input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price" name="price" size="30" type="text" onChange="updatePrice()" />
<input class="span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount" readonly="readonly" value=""/>​


function updatePrice() {
    var price = $("#dare_price").val();
    var total = (price + 1) * 1.05;
    $("$total_price_amount").val(total);
}​
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QWSQp/57/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QWSQp/62/ -- It's important to wrap this in `$(document).ready(...);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#dare_price").change(function(){
   var total = Number($this).val()) + ...;
   $('#total_price').val(total);
});
```

If you programatically change the values, you need to pipeline them through your method -

```
function changePrice(value){
   $('#dare_price').val(value);
   $('#dare_price').trigger('change');
}
```

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/QWSQp/64/) for this event-driven approach.

Answer (score 13):

A couple of things.

1. Firstly I'd use the newest version of jQuery if I were you.
   We're on 1.8 now.
2. I'd also use "keyup" as the event trigger as well as "change". it's just more usable in my opinion. I like to bind events using jQuery also. See http://api.jquery.com/on/
3. there were some errors in your code. Note the `$("$total_price_amount")`  part was throwing an error
4. If you want to only show a set number of decimal point, use `.toFixed()`. But note that this will return a string.
5. input values from text boxes are type `string`, so to do mathematical calculations with them you need to parse them to an `int` or a `float`

## Here's my updated JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/QWSQp/71/

## And the actual code I used

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function updatePrice()
    {
        var price = parseFloat($("#dare_price").val());
        var total = (price + 1) * 1.05;
        var total = total.toFixed(2);
        $("#total_price_amount").val(total);
    }
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price", updatePrice);
});
```

**note** that I removed the `onChange="updatePrice()"` part from the HTML as it's no longer needed.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Just looks like a typo

```
$("$total_price_amount").val(total);
```

Should be

```
$("#total_price_amount").val(total);
```

Use the '#' to get the id

Answer (score 2):

Just to be safe you should `parseFloat()` your price. Also, before doing any of this you should make sure it is even a number to begin with! Otherwise you'll get **`NaN`**

```
function updatePrice() {
    var price = $("#dare_price").val();
    var total = (parseFloat(price) + 1) * 1.05;
    console.log(total);

    // Other big problem was the $total_price_amount typo that should of had # instead
    $("#total_price_amount").val(total);
}​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xjFG5/1/)

Comment: Given the decimal nature of the numbers, `parseFloat()` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example with the change event. You can use events like keydown or -up, whatever suits to your purposes.(The live-method is used for elements created during runtime.)

```
  $('#first').live("change", (function(){       
            $('#idofinputfield').val('mynewvalue');         
    }))
```