# How do I use jQuery to change a field when another field value has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I searched and even with answers like [JQuery: Change value when value of other input field is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287996/jquery-change-value-when-value-of-other-input-field-is-changed), I have been unable to figure this out.

I am trying to do some math based on HTML form input. When the user enters numbers in the first and second field, I want it to automatically calculate into the third field to show the total.

My form code is:

```
<div id="makingARecurringGift">
    Enter Recurring Gift Amount: $<input type="number" min="0" name="recurringDonationValue" id="recurringDonationValue" size="15" value="0" /><br />
    I would like to make this gift for <input type="number" min="0" max="60" name="numberOfMonths" id="numberOfMonths" size="15" value="0" /> months.<br />
    Total Gift Amount of $<input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="totalRecurringDonationValue" />.
</div>
```

My javascript that I am trying to run is:

```
function replaceRecurringDonationValue() {
    //make our variables so we don't forget
    var perDonationValue = 0;
    var numberOfMonths = 0;
    var TotalRecurringDonationValue = 0;

    //give them their correct values
    perDonationValue = $("#recurringDonationValue").val();
    numberOfMonths = $("#numberOfMonths").val();

    //ensure that the maximum number of months is enforced.
    if(numberOfMonths > 60) {
        alert("Donations can last for a maximum of 60 months.");
        $("#numberOfMonths").val(60);
    }

    TotalRecurringDonationValue = perDonationValue * numberOfMonths;

    $("#TotalRecurringDonationValue").val(TotalRecurringDonationValue);
}
$("#recurringDonationValue").change(replaceRecurringDonationValue());
$("#numberOfMonths").change(replaceRecurringDonationValue());
```

If you would like to view the full main page source code:
http://pastebin.com/aLMqYuxc
and full javascript source is:
http://pastebin.com/FvviPHhj

Sorry if this is a dumb question, thank you all for your assistance. I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Also, when I included an `alert();` in the javascript, it was firing when the page loaded, and did not fire when the values changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this:

```
$("#recurringDonationValue").change(replaceRecurringDonationValue());
```

to this:

```
  $("#recurringDonationValue").change(function(){
                                          replaceRecurringDonationValue();
                                       });
```

and this:

```
$("#numberOfMonths").change(replaceRecurringDonationValue());
```

to this:

```
$("#numberOfMonths").change(function(){
                               replaceRecurringDonationValue()
                               });
```

Good shout by Anders,

Even better Combine the two selectors e.g.

```
 $("#recurringDonationValue, #numberOfMonths").change(function(){
                                              replaceRecurringDonationValue();
                                           });
```

Less Code keep it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) :)

Comment: Ah that's perfect. Now it's occurring when the fields change. Can't believe it was so simple. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I would like to explain why, but I will probably make a hash of it. Basically you need to wrap the call to the method, otherwise the method just runs on page load.... Maybe someone can offer a better explanation?

Comment: That makes sense. I hadn't considered that before though. That's been added to the list of things not to repeat :)

Answer (score 1):

Three things...

Change this:

```
Total Gift Amount of $<input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="totalRecurringDonationValue" />.
```

To this:

```
Total Gift Amount of $<input type="number" min="0" value="0" id="totalRecurringDonationValue" />.
```

Change this:

```
$("#TotalRecurringDonationValue").val(TotalRecurringDonationValue);
```

To this:

```
$("#totalRecurringDonationValue").val(TotalRecurringDonationValue);
```

And lastly, change this:

```
$("#recurringDonationValue").change(replaceRecurringDonationValue());
$("#numberOfMonths").change(replaceRecurringDonationValue());
```

To this:

```
$("#recurringDonationValue,#numberOfMonths").change(replaceRecurringDonationValue);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was great to help consolidate the code better! Thank you so much!