# Is there a way to manipulate a portion of the value of an HTML checkbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am new to coding and trying to build something on my own. Unsure of how to even ask so others can understand. I have tried googling and looking around but cannot find the information that I need. For example I have this:

input name="generic_name" value="added $(price) to total amount due"

Is there a way that I can using a window prompt with jQuery to change the (price) section based off input from user? Don't want to change the formatting of the value if possible. Would just like to be able to target that (price) section and change accordingly.

Comment: Hard to understand the context based on what you have described.  For inputs, the value usually has meaning and you seem to want to dynamically change that.  Are you sure you don't want to just change the text of a label?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you've tried otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic). To me it sounds like you need to do [more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418).

Comment: I apologize if I said something that made them seem "off-topic". I have been coding for about a month and unsure about the nuances of this website. Tried to explain the best way I could. I have tried multiple different ways to change what I needed changed and have been trying to research this for a couple weeks now. But hard to explain what I need to do when unsure of what terms to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: Change value when value of other input field is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287996/jquery-change-value-when-value-of-other-input-field-is-changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var oldString = $('input [name="generic_name"]').val();
var newValue = [Whatever you want]; //you can grab value from an input field user is using
var newString = oldString.replace("price", newValue);
 $('input [name="generic_name"]').val(newString );
```

This will grab the full string value, replace the specified substring, and replace the old value with the new value.

Comment: Thanks very much. This was exactly what I was looking for. I would give you an upvote but I don't has the powa!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this JS Fiddle :-

https://jsfiddle.net/36r54z88/5/

```
function changePrice(){
    newPrice = $('#userPrice').val();
        $('#price').html(newPrice);
}
```

userPrice is the id of the text box where you are taking user input and price is the id of the element where you are displaying price.